# ConcurrentModificationException using mylocation overlay and timer

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps, concurrentmodification, mapactivity

this problem has been doing my head in and I hope you can help! I've found the answers to a number of issues here before and hoping you people can work your magic again :)

Ok so part of my app uses the Google Maps API to display an overlay on the map (using a custom overlay class) as well as the users location using mylocationoverlay. Now if I don't activate the mylocationoverlay everything works fine but if its activated then the app force closes with a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Now the timer is used to refresh the overlay as its position is always changing. For this I used an async task to remove the overlay and add a new one with the updated position. Am I correct to assume the mylocationoverlay does a similar thing in the background? If that assumption is valid then I have come to the conclusion that the mylocationoverlay and my async task are attempting to iterate/modify the same array at the same time. The only this is, I have no idea how to stop this from happening!

I can't really post my code here as its very big but I used an example code taken from github created by commonsguy and modified it to produce the same issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been really really frustrating me. Thanks in advance and sorry for the long description!

Edit: Link for commonsguy code is - https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Maps/NooYawkAsync/

Edit 2: Added error trace after java code.

```
package com.commonsware.android.maps;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MyLocationOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class NooYawk extends MapActivity {
    private MapView map=null;
    private MyLocationOverlay me=null;
    private SitesOverlay sites=null;
    public Timer timer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        map=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);

        map.getController().setCenter(getPoint(40.76793169992044, -73.98180484771729));
        map.getController().setZoom(17);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        me=new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
        me.enableMyLocation();
        map.getOverlays().add(me);

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 10000, 10000);

        new OverlayTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        me.enableMyLocation();
        me.enableCompass();
    }       

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        me.disableMyLocation();
        me.disableCompass();
    }       

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return(false);
    }

    private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat, double lon) {
        return(new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1000000.0), (int)(lon*1000000.0)));
    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// TIMER CLASS //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        new OverlayTask().execute();
    }
}


    private class SitesOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<CustomItem> {
        private Drawable heart=null;
        private List<CustomItem> items=new ArrayList<CustomItem>();

        public SitesOverlay() {
            super(null);

            heart=getMarker(R.drawable.heart_full);

            items.add(new CustomItem(getPoint(40.748963847316034, -73.96807193756104),
                                                "UN", "United Nations", getMarker(R.drawable.blue_full_marker), heart));
            populate();
        }

        @Override
        protected CustomItem createItem(int i) {
            return(items.get(i));
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return(items.size());
        }

        void toggleHeart() {
            CustomItem focus=getFocus();

            if (focus!=null) {
                focus.toggleHeart();
            }

            map.invalidate();
        }

        private Drawable getMarker(int resource) {
            Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(resource);

            marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(), marker.getIntrinsicHeight());
            boundCenter(marker);

            return(marker);
        }
    }

    class PopupPanel {
        View popup;
        boolean isVisible=false;

        PopupPanel(int layout) {
            ViewGroup parent=(ViewGroup)map.getParent();

            popup=getLayoutInflater().inflate(layout, parent, false);

            popup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    hide();
                }
            });
        }

        View getView() {
            return(popup);
        }

        void show(boolean alignTop) {
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );

            if (alignTop) {
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                lp.setMargins(0, 20, 0, 0);
            }
            else {
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
                lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 60);
            }

            hide();

            ((ViewGroup)map.getParent()).addView(popup, lp);
            isVisible=true;
        }

        void hide() {
            if (isVisible) {
                isVisible=false;
                ((ViewGroup)popup.getParent()).removeView(popup);
            }
        }
    }

    class CustomItem extends OverlayItem {
        Drawable marker=null;
        boolean isHeart=false;
        Drawable heart=null;

        CustomItem(GeoPoint pt, String name, String snippet, Drawable marker, Drawable heart) {
            super(pt, name, snippet);

            this.marker=marker;
            this.heart=heart;
        }

        @Override
        public Drawable getMarker(int stateBitset) {
            Drawable result=(isHeart ? heart : marker);

            setState(result, stateBitset);

            return(result);
        }

        void toggleHeart() {
            isHeart=!isHeart;
        }
    }

    class OverlayTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            if (sites!=null) {
                map.getOverlays().remove(sites);
                map.postInvalidate();   
                sites=null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            //SystemClock.sleep(5000);                      // simulated work

            sites=new SitesOverlay();

            return(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            map.getOverlays().add(sites);
            map.postInvalidate();           
        }
    }
}
```

## Stack Trace:

java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.draw(OverlayBundle.java:44)
at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:494)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1847)
at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Please provide a link to the specific code you're referencing.  https://github.com/commonsguy ...?

Comment: Can you tell from the error output what data structure is generating the exception?

Comment: Sorry about that. link is - https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Maps/NooYawkAsync . Added link to the description too. Also I cant really tell what is generating the error, I'll post the error here in a moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you removing and replacing the overlay?

Why not leave the overlay alone, and change its marker? Just call `populate()` again on the `ItemizedOverlay` and it will call `size()` and `getItem()` all over again. Just be sure to return the new correct data.

Your error definitely feels like it is tied to adding and removing the overlay. In fact, I thought perhaps you were doing that in `doInBackground()`, but you're not. Hence, I would have thought that what you're doing would be safe from a threading standpoint, just overkill from a processing standpoint.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply but I'm not quite following what you mean by change the marker. Are you referring to the getmarker() method? I don't see how I can set a new lat, lon in that way. Sorry if its simple but I'm still fairly new to this.

Comment: @RadicalApps: There's not much I can say that I didn't say in the answer itself: call `populate()` on the `ItemizedOverlay`, and have your `size()` and `getItem()` methods on your `ItemizedOverlay` return the right data. The map should redraw itself. Do not remove the overlay. Do not add the overlay. Just call `populate()` on the overlay, to have it reload its markers with your fresh data.

Comment: Ah right I'm following now! It was whether I should add/remove the markers still that was confusing me. I'll give that a go in just a moment.

Comment: You are a total legend! Thanks so much that worked like a charm :D Took a bit of time to get my head round it but it works great! Most likely going to subscribe to your books too, they look really interesting. Thanks again :D

Comment: @RadicalApps: I'm a man. I may be a myth. I doubt I'm a legend. Glad to hear it worked for you, and thanks for the kind words regarding the books!

Comment: @RadicalApps: Could you update your java code above with the solution that now works?